# Android/HTC One screen anomaly?

Tags: screen, htc-one

I was wondering what has happened to my HTC One. Is it a hardware issue or an Android/software issue?

The screen has usually moved half way between when I enter and exit any app. Since a picture speaks a thousand words:

[image]

Notice in the picture/screenshot from my phone, that I have a partial view of both screens. That is strange and I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: I've seen this once or twice on my old Galaxy Nexus and even on my Moto X, where a swipe from one screen to the next seems to have gotten stuck half way. If a restart hasn't fixed it, try clearing the data for the launcher.

Comment: Happens on my Galaxy S4 the odd time. Sometimes it's due to a little sweat or dirt on the screen, sometimes it seems to be the launcher. Why not install a free launcher (I love nova personally) and see if it persists. You can swap back to blinkfeed at any time and see. Narrow it down to software issue hopefully and proceed from there!

Answer (score -1):

It most certainly is not a hardware related issue.
I would begin by rebooting the device.

Comment: Rebooted. Problem still occurs. Do you think it might be some sort of micro-crack propagation in the screen?

Comment: The screen still responds to touch when you slide left-right ?

Comment: Yes, the screen responds to swiping and returns to its "correct" state of being centered on a single screen.

Comment: If this was a hardware issue, the whole screen including the notification bar and the bottom menu would be shifted, and it wouldn't appear in screenshots.

Comment: Rebooting doesn't help, and a hardware issue is very unlikely... Clearing the data and Cache for the Launcher app would be next step.

Go into Settings / Apps , swipe to the right untill it says "All" instead of "Downloaded" or "Running", 
I don't know what the HTC launcher is called, but chances are it will have the word "launcher" in the name. Select that one and push on Clear Cache and Clear Data in the next screen.

This ought to reset the Launcher app to defaults.

Answer (score -1):

Change your font size, that fixes the same problem for me.